# Swift/JSONEncoder: Encoding class containing a nested raw JSON object literal

Tags: json, swift, jsonencoder

I have a class in Swift whose structure resembles this:

```swift
class MyClass {
  var name: String
  var data: String
}
```

Which could be initialised where `data` contains a JSON object encoded as a String.

```swift
var instance = MyClass()
instance.name = "foo"
instance.data = "{\"bar\": \"baz\"}"
```

I'd now like to serialise this instance using `JSONEncoder`, I'd get an output similar to this:

```json
{
  "name": "foo",
  "data": "{\"bar\": \"baz\"}"
}
```

However, what I'd really like

```json
{
  "name": "foo",
  "data": {
    "bar": "baz"
  }
}
```

Can I achieve this with JSONEncoder? (without changing the `data` type away from `String`)

Comment: Do you know the structure of  `data`?

Comment: No, which is why I don't what to make an effort of decoding/encoding it.

Comment: (Almost) everything is possible, but the less standard the model  is the more code you have to write. As you are going to **encode** the stuff use a more suitable design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll first need to decode `data` as generic JSON. That's a bit tedious, but not too difficult. See [RNJSON](https://github.com/rnapier/RNJSON/blob/main/Sources/RNJSON/RNJSON.swift) for a version I wrote, or here's a stripped-down version that handles your issues.

```
enum JSON: Codable {
    struct Key: CodingKey, Hashable {
        let stringValue: String
        init(_ string: String) { self.stringValue = string }
        init?(stringValue: String) { self.init(stringValue) }
        var intValue: Int? { return nil }
        init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
    }

    case string(String)
    case number(Double) // FIXME: Split Int and Double
    case object([Key: JSON])
    case array([JSON])
    case bool(Bool)
    case null

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        if let string = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self) { self = .string(string) }
        else if let number = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(Double.self) { self = .number(number) }
        else if let object = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: Key.self) {
            var result: [Key: JSON] = [:]
            for key in object.allKeys {
                result[key] = (try? object.decode(JSON.self, forKey: key)) ?? .null
            }
            self = .object(result)
        }
        else if var array = try? decoder.unkeyedContainer() {
            var result: [JSON] = []
            for _ in 0..<(array.count ?? 0) {
                result.append(try array.decode(JSON.self))
            }
            self = .array(result)
        }
        else if let bool = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(Bool.self) { self = .bool(bool) }
        else if let isNull = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decodeNil(), isNull { self = .null }
        else { throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [],
                                                                       debugDescription: "Unknown JSON type")) }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        switch self {
        case .string(let string):
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try container.encode(string)
        case .number(let number):
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try container.encode(number)
        case .bool(let bool):
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try container.encode(bool)
        case .object(let object):
            var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: Key.self)
            for (key, value) in object {
                try container.encode(value, forKey: key)
            }
        case .array(let array):
            var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
            for value in array {
                try container.encode(value)
            }
        case .null:
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            try container.encodeNil()
        }
    }
}
```

With that, you can decode the JSON and then re-encode it:

```
extension MyClass: Encodable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case name, data
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)

        let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(JSON.self, from: Data(data.utf8))
        try container.encode(json, forKey: .data)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very useful utility, it solved the issue nicely. I'm surprised there wasn't something already included with `JSONEncoder `. Perhaps I've been spoilt by Newtonsoft.Json. I'll have to fix the Int/Double abiguity though.

Comment: I've been working on this a bit more today (see github); what Int/Double ambiguity do you need to fix? I've done some work there. I'm now storing the value internally as an NSNumber, which helps.

Comment: I just found the code through your RNJSON link. I have recently answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68367281/669586) and I think some of the code could be definitely simplified. However, unlike me, you are solving `null` cases which I ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```swift
extension MyClass {
    func jsonFormatted() throws -> String? {
        guard let data = data.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        let anyData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        let dictionary = ["name": name, "data": anyData] as [String : Any]
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
        return jsonString
    }
}
```

So basically, you leave the structure of `data` intact, but the rest is wrapped in a dictionary that can be converted to that json string you want to achieve.
Note you'll need to handle the optional and errors that could be thrown.
You can use this to test:

```swift
if let jsonString = try? instance.jsonFormatted() {
    print(jsonString)
}
```