# Problem encoding JSON for a UrlRequest in Swift

Tags: swift, urlsession, json-serialization, urlrequest

I'm trying to set up an API service. I have a simple login call that looks like this:

```
enum HttpMethod: Equatable {
    case get([URLQueryItem])
    case put(Data?)
    case post(Data?)

    var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .get: return "GET"
        case .put: return "PUT"
        case .post: return "POST"
        }
    }
}

struct Request<Response> {
    let url: URL
    let method: HttpMethod
    var headers: [String: String] = [:]
}

extension Request {
    static func postUserLogin(email: String, password:String) -> Self {
        var params = [String: Any]()
        params["username"] = email
        params["password"] = password
        let data = params.jsonData

        return Request(
            url: URL(string: NetworkingConstants.USER_LOGIN)!,
            method: .post(
                try? JSONEncoder().encode(data) //should this be something else???
            )
        )
    }
}

extension Dictionary {
    var jsonData: Data? {
        return try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: [.prettyPrinted])
    }
}

extension Request {
    var urlRequest: URLRequest {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        switch method {
        case .post(let data), .put(let data):
            request.httpBody = data

        case let .get(queryItems):
            //removed for brevity
        default:
            break
        }

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpMethod = method.name
        return request
    }
}

extension URLSession {
    func decode<Value: Decodable>(
        _ request: Request<Value>,
        using decoder: JSONDecoder = .init()
    ) async throws -> Value {
        let decoded = Task.detached(priority: .userInitiated) {
            let (data, _) = try await self.data(for: request.urlRequest)
            try Task.checkCancellation()
            return try decoder.decode(Value.self, from: data)
        }
        return try await decoded.value
    }
}
```

The problem is, instead of the Body of the request being sent to the server looking like this:

```
{
    "username": "me@you.com",
    "password": "abcdef"
}
```

It looks like this:

```
"eyJwYXNzd29yZCI6ImFhYWEiLCJ1cZSI6InRhQHQuY29tIn0="
```

What am I doing wrong? Here's how I make the call:

```
let request: Request<UserLoginResponse> = .postUserLogin(email: "me@you.com", password: "abcdef")
let response = try? await URLSession.shared.decode(request)
```

request.httpBody looks like this:

```
▿ Optional<Data>
  ▿ some : 74 bytes
    - count : 74
    ▿ pointer : 0x00007fcc74011200
      - pointerValue : 140516096283136
```

Comment: Are you certain that what you've given as the output (`"eyJw...`) is the real output? That looks corrupted. It's the beginning of Base64-encoded JSON, but looks like it's missing a couple of characters in the middle, and it decodes to a password "aaaa" rather than "abcdf".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` are designed to work directly with Swift types allowing you to skip the need to build generic dictionaries or arrays as you are doing where you have this code:

```
// You should use a Swift type instead of this
var params = [String: Any]()
params["username"] = email
params["password"] = password
let data = params.jsonData
```

In your case you should declare a `struct` and mark it as `Codable` then encode that (from a playground):

```
struct UserAuthentication: Codable {
    let username: String
    let password: String
}

let email = "fred"
let password = "foobar"

let userAuthentication = UserAuthentication(username: email, password: password)
let encoder = JSONEncoder()

do {
    let encoded = try encoder.encode(userAuthentication)
    print(String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8)!)
} catch (let error) {
    print("Json Encoding Error \(error)")
}
```

Swift will represent your struct (in this case the `UserAuthentication` struct) as JSON using the names of the properties as the JSON keys and their values as the JSON values.

If you want to handle more complex cases, see:

[Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

Comment: Thanks, this works. But what if I need to allow for a generic set of params in the `UserAuthentication` struct? Such as `let params: [String:Any]?` For example, if along with username and password, I need to pass to the backend some dictionary of extra data like `{"prefs": "cats", "age": 23}`. The keys will be strings but the values could be strings, ints, floats, etc. And the keys can vary.

Comment: If you really cannot know the list of keys and types, then you'll want to use something like a JSON type. Lots of people have written them (here's a small one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65901928/swift-jsonencoder-encoding-class-containing-a-nested-raw-json-object-literal/65902852#65902852)  But you should make sure that's really your problem. Most server APIs take specific values or sometimes `[String:String]`, rather than "any key, with any JSON."  (Nothing can encode  every `[String:Any]` into JSON. JSON cannot encode a UIViewController or CBPeripheral, which are Any values.)

Comment: You *could* use Dictionaries and Arrays and use [JSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization) instead of JSONEncoder/Decoder.  But I generally prefer schemes that can preserve type information.

Answer (score 3):

Scott Thompson's answer is correct in the general case, and worth learning. In this specific case you can make it a bit simpler because you happen to have a `[String: String]` dictionary, which is already Encodable. So you don't need an extra encoding type:

```
static func postUserLogin(email: String, password:String) -> Self {
    var params = [String: String]()
    params["username"] = email
    params["password"] = password

    return Request(
        url: URL(string: NetworkingConstants.USER_LOGIN)!,
        method: .post(
            try? JSONEncoder().encode(params)
        )
    )
}
```

Your problem is that you're first JSONSerialization-encoding `params` into a Data that contains the JSON characters. You then JSONEncoder-encoding that Data, which by default Base64-encodes it. That's the "ey..." output you're getting. There's no need for two steps. You can get rid of `jsonData` entirely, and just use JSONEncoder directly.

Comment: Thanks. This does work, but you're right, only for [String: String], and not [String: Any]. I guess I'll have to go the route on Scott's answer and define structs for each different type of inputs that I need to use.

Comment: If you have a JSON payload that you want structs for, do see https://app.quicktype.io. It will write all the code for you.