# How to encode a dictionary of unknown/variable keys?

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable, encodable

Say I have to send this data to the server:

```
struct Event: Codable {
    let title: String
    let params: [String:Any]? //Not allowed
}
```

So for instance, these events could look like any of these:

```
let event = Event(title: "cat was pet", params:["age": 7.2])
let event = Event(title: "cat purred", params:["time": 9])
let event = Event(title: "cat drank", params:["water": "salty", "amount": 3.3])
```

I need the ability to send any arbitrary amount of key/value pairs as `params` to the event. Is this even possible with `Codable`? If not, how would I encode `params` as a json string?

Comment: Can the params' values _really_ be `Any`? E.g. Can I pass a UIViewController as a param value? You'll most likely want to constrain it to a narrower set of JSON-supported (or Encodable) types

Comment: Probably just strings, ints, and floats.

Comment: Was there a problem with the JSON type I discussed on the last question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65901928/swift-jsonencoder-encoding-class-containing-a-nested-raw-json-object-literal/65902852#65902852  For a version with basically this exact syntax, see https://github.com/rnapier/RNAJSON/tree/main/Sources/JSONValue

Comment: @RobNapier I don't quite follow that answer. How would my `Event` struct need to change to accommodate that? Could you post an answer here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Codable` is magic if all types conform to `Codable`, but in your case I suggest traditional `JSONSerialization`. Add a computed property `dictionaryRepresentation`

```
struct Event: {
    let title: String
    let params: [String:Any]

    var dictionaryRepresentation: [String:Any] {
        return ["title":title,"params":params] 
    }
}
```

then encode the event

```
let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: event.dictionaryRepresentation)
```

This is less expensive/cumbersome than forcing `Any` to become `Codable` (no offense, Rob).

Comment: thanks. Events isn't an array though. I'm just POSTing one event at a time.

Comment: Still easier. Please see the edit

Answer (score 1):

Using a type like [JSONValue](https://github.com/RNCodable/JSONValue), it would look almost identical to what you describe:

```
import JSONValue

struct Event: Codable {
    let title: String
    let params: JSONValue?  // JSONValue rather than [String: Any]
}

// All the rest is the same
let event1 = Event(title: "cat was pet", params:["age": 7.2])
let event2 = Event(title: "cat purred", params:["time": 9])
let event3 = Event(title: "cat drank", params:["water": "salty", "amount": 3.3])
```

There's a lot of helper code in JSONValue, but at its heart is just an enum, as described in [Swift/JSONEncoder: Encoding class containing a nested raw JSON object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65901928/swift-jsonencoder-encoding-class-containing-a-nested-raw-json-object-literal/65902852#65902852):

```
public enum JSONValue {
    case string(String)
    case number(digits: String)
    case bool(Bool)
    case object([String: JSONValue])
    case array([JSONValue])
    case null
}
```

Everything else is just helpers to encode/decode, conform to `ExpressibleBy...` protocols, etc.

Comment: Appreciate it. Going to go with `JSONSerialization` for brevity here, but this is good to know.